# Url not working when pod is deployed to kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying Kubernetes Deployment to deploy pod with some image.

**service-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: service-deployment
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   component: web
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    component: web
  spec:
   containers:
    - name: magic-card-service
      image: vineelpellella/magic-card-service:2.0
      ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
```

**service-node-port.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
 name: service-node-port
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30232
 selector:
  component: web
```

after deploying using kubectl with docker desktop I am unable to open URL
localhost:30232/api/participants/2

Not sure what is going wrong here

Comment: Are you running kubernetes locally? It's not clear from the question why you would expect to access the service on `localhost`.

Comment: yes running in local along with docker desktop

Answer (score 0):

After restart of the machine, this seems to be working fine without any changes in the config files